# I am trying to develop an application which requires the below UI:

Tags: android

I know its not a feasible thing to run a ListView with-in ListView or with-in a ScrollView. So I'll like to know that Is there any other way to do this same thing ? as the UI has to be same as its running in its LIVE iOS App.

[image: End level add item in listview.]

Comment: Use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: @kalpesh its feasible, you can use expandable listview

Comment: for one of ref. https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView

Comment: dynamic add item end level.  1)cloth -> shirt -> Formal Shirt -> Lining -> red color